# Shapely Buffering, not working as expected

Tags: python, gis, geopandas, shapely, apache-sedona

Why does buffering one of my geometries have an unexpected hole in it?

```
from shapely import LineString
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame

l = LineString([
  (250,447),
  (319,446),
  (325,387),
  (290,374),
  (259,378),
  (254,385),
  (240,409),
  (244,440),
  (250,447),
])

assert l.is_valid
assert l.is_simple

GeoDataFrame({'geometry': [
  l,
  l.buffer(80),
]}).plot(column='geometry')
```

[image: holey buffered geometry]

- By removing a pair of coordinates, it doesn't have a hole.
- When using Sedona's `ST_Buffer` this happened in more cases.

Comment: It fills the hole when using this LineRing:
`l = LineString([(250,447),(319,446),(325,387),(290,374),(259,378),(254,385),(240,409),(250,447)])`

Comment: I expect there to be a hole when I buffer less:  `l.buffer(40)`

Comment: My hack solution is to buffer a tiny amount to make a polygon:  `l.buffer(1e-6).buffer(80)`

Answer (score 0):

```
from shapely import LineString
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame

l = LineString([
  (250,447),
  (319,446),
  (325,387),
  (290,374),
  (259,378),
  (254,385),
  (240,409),
  (244,440),
  (250,447),
])

l = l.simplify(tolerance=1e-6)

buffered_geometry = l.buffer(80, cap_style=3, join_style=2)

GeoDataFrame({'geometry': [l, buffered_geometry]}).plot(column='geometry')
```

which is basically what you did.

[image]

Comment: However `l.is_valid == True`, and there is no self-intersection expect starting and ending in the same point, which simplify doesn't alter.  In fact simplifying at 1 drops one pair of coordinates which I have already tested to work.  And simplifying lower does not work.

Comment: My apologies. I updated my answer.

Comment: Is this expected behaviour?  
I wasn't expecting it, and it doesn't happen with many similar geometries.  
How can we predict this?

Comment: As you write, it doesn't happen very often. The times it has, I have tried to understand why but not found the source of it....and then I let it go.

Comment: This is a known JTS bug: https://github.com/locationtech/jts/issues/876